# Adding a node to a hash table

Tags: c

When I'm trying to add my node to my hash table I'm getting seg fault. I've used gdb but can't pin point why I'm getting this error.

```
int symbol_add (sym_table_t* symTab, const char* name, int addr) {
  int hash = 0;
  int index = 0;    
  if(symbol_search(symTab, name, &hash, &index) == NULL){
    struct node pointer = calloc (1,sizeof(struct node));
    pointer->symbol.name = strdup(name);
    pointer->symbol.addr = addr;
    pointer->hash = hash;
    pointer->next = symTab -> hash_table[index];
    symTab->hash_table[index] = pointer;
    return 1;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Could the index value returned by `symbol_search` be out of range?

Comment: Can you share some details from gdb? Like a stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Will this piece of code even compile?

```
struct node pointer = calloc (1,sizeof(struct node));
```

I think it should be changed to the following:

```
struct node * pointer = calloc (1,sizeof(struct node));
```

Answer (score 1):

1. As [@bialpio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26952624/2410359) posted, change variable declaration to `struct node * pointer`.  As code stands, doubtful the code compiled or code posted is not the true code.
2. Recommend a better `calloc()` style, which would have caught this coding problem.

   ```
   struct node *pointer = calloc(1, sizeof *pointer);
   ```
3. Certainly, not all warnings are enabled.  Save yourself time and enable them.